# Bndtools on a multi module maven Project

Tags: osgi, multi-module, bnd, bndtools

I am currently working on migrating a multi module maven osgi project to bnd tools.

What I'm struggling with is the configuration of the `build.bnd` so I can build the bundles.

If I add a package to the export list i get:

> Error finding source package for exported 1 packages

and in the details:

> java.lang.NullPointerException

This I understand is due to the directory layout, which is one main folder including all the projects and the parent pom listing all the modules.
so basically the structure is

```
myMultiMavenProject//project1 
myMultiMavenProject//project2 
myMultiMavenProject//pom.xml
```

and the bundles to build are the maven projects themselves, each containing its own `bnd.bnd` defining the bundle

I already changed the basic project layout to maven for all projects using what bndtools generates when you create a new project and select said option

Then I tried to edit the `build.bnd` and change directories to something like project:

```
${basedir}//myMultiMavenProject
```

and I still fail to get a build.

I'm working on Windows 7, already had path problems configuring plugins and had to keep those in mind.
The bndtools core doesn't work well with those paths in case you use the UI for it.

Answer (score 0):

bnd does not support nested projects. That is, each project must be in the workspace folder as a peer to the cnf folder.

Comment: That i know, and exactly here is my point. Since it is the only other project in the workspace and nothing else is to be build, it should be possible to change the directory structure to fit this one project and build the bundles